# Flask-wtf dynamic select field with an empty option

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I want to populate a select field based a query search.

But I also want an empty option.

This is my current code

```
 form.state.choices=[(s.id, s.name) for s in State.query.all()]
```

the result is

```
  <select>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
  <option value="FL">Florida</option>
  </select>
```

the desired result is

```
<select>
<option value=""></option>
<option value="CA">California</option>
<option value="FL">Florida</option>
</select>
```

It would be cool if is also not valid if the select option is empty.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may want to add the empty value like this:

```
choices = [("", "---")]
form.state.choices=[choices.append((s.id, s.name)) for s in State.query.all()]
```

Then you can check whether the value is empty string to validate the field.

Comment: is there a way to specify a different font for the first tuple?  Specifically, the color so that it might be 'greyed out'?

Comment: It's not working in Python 3.7.3. But work when I use @fab answer.

Comment: `[mylist.append(x) for x in some_sequence]` will return a list of `None`s.

Comment: I don't know why this is the accepted answer; it's just plain wrong. As @snakecharmerb says, this results in a list of `None`. Answer from @fab below should be accepted.

Answer (score 15):

You cound add the empty value also in the same line:

`form.state.choices=[("", "---")]+[(s.id, s.name) for s in State.query.all()]`